# Adding to a backpack issues

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to create a GUI in which if a button is clicked the player has an item added to their backpack. I've tried my own solutions and tried using roblox's own solution, but it still does not work

```
    local ss = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(player, tool)
    local backpack = player:FindFirstChildOfClass("Backpack")
    tool = ss.Sabre:Clone()
    tool.Parent = backpack
end)
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all button was never defined in your code. Secondly, player and tool and never passed when a button is clicked. Try this instead

```lua
local ss = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local button = PATH_TO_YOUR_BUTTON -- Put your path here
button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local player = game.Player.LocalPlayer
    local backpack = player:FindFirstChildOfClass("Backpack")
    local tool = ss.Sabre:Clone()
    tool.Parent = backpack
end)
```

But even with this you will still encounter an issue. You are giving the tool locally, so only that player will actually see the tool. I suggest and read about [Remote Events](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Remote-Functions-and-Events)

Comment: I might be wrong about the player thing, because I've never actually done something like that.

Comment: This still does not work for some reason

Comment: Cmb, when you give people suggestions, you should be careful how you denote psuedo-code. Beginners may have difficulty understanding the difference between your example and what they need to do to fix it. Rather than using `<button>` it might be clearer if you defined it on the line above it with something like `local button = PATH_TO_YOUR_BUTTON -- fix this`

Comment: I got the local button part down but it still won't work.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your output?

Comment: Nope, no errors nothing. The example roblox provided and my own solutions had no errors and simply just stacks run and stuff.

Comment: I have a question. Where is this script located in your game?

Comment: Directly parented to the button we defined before

Comment: Is the original parent of the UI object inside of StarterGui? Or a SurfaceGui?

Comment: It's inside the startergui

Comment: Okay. I see nothing wrong with your scripts and I do not see anything that can fix you issue. I might be able to send another answer as an error handler to check for errors.